# ModernHttpClient vs AndroidClientHandler

Tags: .net, http, xamarin

My team is refining our network stack and trying to decide between defaulting to ModernHttpClient vs. “Native” project settings in iOS and Android.

I can see a few differences and I was wondering if anyone had an opinion on which approach would be the best default solution:

- ModernHttpClient seems to use OkHttp instead of AndroidClientHandler.  Which do you consider more robust?
- AndroidClientHandler seems to have a specific way to handle network errors, wrapping them in an Exception. ModernHttpClient seems to use a different exception.
- ModernHttpClient seems to have the beginnings of a pre-Authentication mechanism.  AndroidClientHandler seems to lack it.
- AndroidClientHandler provides free support for self-signed Certs.

Any and all guidance on the topic will be greatly appreciataed.